# Comparing Java arrays

Tags: java

I have two parallel java arrays that consist of strings. In the first one I have some duplicated values that have more than one match in the second array. I'm trying to collect the duplicated values and store them in a Set of strings, I also want to collect the matching value in a set of strings. Example of what I want to do is this:

```
apple        1
orange       2
apple        3
orange       4
nuts         5
```

I want them to be like this:

```
[apple] [1,3]
[orange]  [2,4]
[nuts]    [5]
```

Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: java.util.Map is your friend.

Comment: @kocko - More specifically `Map<String, List<Integer>>` (or use `Set` instead of `List` to get rid of dups).

Comment: as a side note, it's always a good idea to show us what you have done. Generally speaking, getting an answer around your code will help you better understand the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `Map<String, List<Integer>>` instead. Just iterate over the two arrays, and add the values as *key-value* pair.

Before adding each time, check whether the key is already there using [`Map#containsKey(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) method. If it is already there, get the `List` corresponding to that key, using [`Map#get(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) method, and then add the new element in the list using [`List#add(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map<String,List<Integer>>` , iterate through the `int[]` and fetch the value from `String[]` array by index and keep populating the `Map`.

The keys of the `Map` shall be the values in `String[]` and the values will be the `List<Integer>`. Check if a *key* exists in the `Map` , if exists , then add the integer value to the `List<Integer>` or else create an entry with that String as key and a new List containing the integer value.

An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be :

```
String[] keys = {"apple","orange","apple","orange","nuts"};
int[] values = {1,2,3,4,5};
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String,List<Integer>>();
for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
    int value = values[i];
    String key = keys[i];
    if(map.containsKey(key)){
        map.get(key).add(value);
    }
    else {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(value);
        map.put(key, list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic you need (in pseudo-code):

```
map := new Map<String, Set<Integer>>
for each i in array do
    key := array[i][0]
    value := array[i][1]
    if map not contains key then
        map.add(key, new Set<Integer>)
    endif
    map.get(key).add(value)
endfor
```